# Skip Arch Linux Login Screen on RPi

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, arch-arm

*(Migrated from RPi Stack Exchange:)*
I want to use my RPi to run a non-terminating executable as a pseudo-OS. Ideally, my Pi would run Arch Linux or an equivalent, but skip Arch's login screen and shell, instead booting directly into my executable. The Pi needs a file system and needs to run a full OS (preferably Linux), but none of that should be visible to the user. In other words, I want to use Arch as a mere "backing" or "skeleton" to write a super-simple OS frontend in a higher-level language like C or C++. **Is there a fairly easy way to start Arch Linux directly into an executable**, so that I can focus more on the application programming than the OS-level programming?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two different things : automatic login and automatic start of programs at startup. Archlinux is based on systemd, and the best in your case is probably to write a systemd unit to start your non-terminating executable at startup, ensuring that its dependencies are started.